# nodejs - pass global variable to promise callback in parse

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, parse-server

consider this code

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    query.equalTo("objectId",data[i].id).first().then(
        function(object){
            object.set("username", data[i].username);
            object.save();
        }
    );
}
```

in this example `data[i]` inside the `then callback` is the last element of the array

consider this 2nd example that normally work in javascript world

assume we use some API which connect to mongodb and has function called update

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    query.eq("_id",data[i].id).update(data[i].username);
}
```

`eq` returns the object, `update` updates that object and save it.

will it not be awesome if something like this is possible ... (not sure if it will also even work)

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    query.equalTo("objectId",data[i].id).first().then(
        function(object, data[i]){
            object.set("username", data.username);
            object.save();
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This actually doesn't work only because of scoping `var`. You can get the sample running as desired just by:

a) using `let` instead of `var`

b) creating a new scope for `i` (this is what `let` basically does). (In the anonymous fn, I used `ii` instead of `i` just for clarity. `i` would also work):

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    (function(ii) {
        query.equalTo("objectId",data[ii].id).first().then(
            function(object){
                object.set("username", data[ii].username);
                object.save();
            }
        );
    })(i)
}
```

Comment: In javascript all variables declared with var are function scoped. You are getting this issue because line data[i].username executes in async manner and that time i is referring to the last(or some other) index of data. To overcome this scenario we use Closure as explained by @Tomas

Comment: @JitendraKhatri @Tomas I think this will not work because in parse we can't pass the variable to the `then callback` ... Tomas used the second example that suggested as a solution `then(function(token, data[i] { ... }` but parse uses `then(function(token) { ... }`

Comment: Yeah, I can see the problem - I just straightforwardly edited the second snippet of code you provided - which is not correct. I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

the best way to solve this problem with `parse` is to use recursivity

```
   ... 

   var do = function(entries, i){
        if (entries[i]){

            let user = data[i];

            query.equalTo("objectId", user.id).first().then(
                function(object){
                    object.set("username", user.username);
                    object.save();
                }
            ).then(
                function(){
                    return do(entries, i + 1);
                }
            );
        }
    }
```